# How to perform fast user switching

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, winlogon

I'm looking for a function that could perform a fast user switching. Something like ExitWindowsEx() or InitiateShutdown(). I searched in MSDN but I could find anything useful. The only thing was that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776893%28v=vs.85%29.aspx but there is nothing how to do it programically. Thanks in advance.

Comment: where do you want to switch users?

Comment: What do you mean by "where"?

Comment: I think I got it now.. You want to switch windows users via an C++ app, right?

Comment: Yes. I want my C++ app to call windows to open fast user switching screen. Something similar to what LockWorkStation() does.

Comment: What is wrong with `LockWorkStation()`? It seems like it is exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: LockWorkStation() does something the same job like clicking "Lock" button on Menu Start. I look for something that would work like clicking "Switch user" button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fast User Switching is implemented via [Remote Desktop Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb892075%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (used to be called Terminal Services), so to initiate the switching screen it's simply a matter of disconnecting the current session:

```
WTSDisconnectSession(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, WTS_CURRENT_SESSION, FALSE);
```